# cylon.js and gsm-shield in arduino

Tags: javascript, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Is there a way to connect and send sms from the arduino uno (with gsm shield) using cylon.js. Do I have to use node gsm.ino library and if so how ? (just like the way we use cylon.js to control devices(LED, motor,etc) connected to arduino)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to connect and send sms from the arduino uno (with gsm
>   shield) using cylon.js.

No.

> Do I have to use node gsm.ino library and if so how ?

Cylon.js requires StandardFirmata.ino on all Arduino family boards.

If you want to send text messages from node.js programs, I recommend using Twilio http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/